# Analysis of Regression Model

Tags: meta-analysis

I have to apologize in advance for this question. I just want a second opinion.

I was given the raw data of a survey. Based on the survey items five factors were created which in combination with demographics led to an outcome variable. This outcome variable for each row of respondent gives a probability of binary outcome (i.e. probability of an event happening vs not happening). 
The predicted outcome was included in the raw dataset. 
Even though we do not have the actual outcome, I was asked to see if I can see any patterns and especially if I can analyze statistically those factors with the predicted outcome. I already told to the people who asked this question that those factors were part of the model that produced a predicted outcome variable and that we do not have the actual outcome to do actual comparisons.
I can describe the patterns on the predicted outcome but I cannot do any further statistical results on a predicted outcome because this predicted outcome is not 100% accurate. Am I missing something? 
Is there a statistical way to examine relationships when the dependent variable is the outcome of an existing model? Any suggestions are welcomed. Again my apologies for the question...